# SFSafariViewController alloc initwithurl returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

Any clue why the `SFSafariViewController` is nil?  I can't seem to get a created Safari View Controller.

```
SFSafariViewController *safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:menuItem.url]];
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of the URL? What iOS version did you check on?

Comment: It maybe cause I am using 8.2.  I figured I would get an error in Xcode but I didnt.  Loading up 9.2 simulator now.

Comment: You remove Xcode although this could be an Xcode problem?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I might get an error but it returns nil if using anything 9 or above of iOS.  This seems to work.

```
if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {
                SFSafariViewController *safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:menuItem.url]];

                [self presentViewController:safariViewController animated:true completion:nil];
            } else {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:menuItem.url]];
            }
```

Comment: Don't do that, it won't even work on iOS 10. Do `if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {`